# Solution formular for Laplace equation 

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

I want to slove the Laplace equation on $R^3_+$ with Neumann boundary condition. The equation reads:
$-\Delta u = f$ in $R^3_+$,
$\partial_3 u|_{x_3=0}=g$ on $R^2$. 
If $f$, $g$ satisfy compatibility condition, can I write the explicit formular of $u$?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the book "Handbook of Linear Partial Differential Equations for Engineers and Scientists" by Polyanin, A. D. Chapman & Hall/CRC, 2002, can help you.

By the way, if $f=0$ the solution (up to a constant because the solution is not unique) is
$$
u(x,y,z)=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}=\frac{g(\mu,\nu)}{\sqrt{(x-\mu)^2+(y-\nu)^2+z^2}}d\nu d\mu.
$$